# How to create linked array of dataframe column based on key using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` like this. I need to create linked list of array of  `df['Id']` based on `df['code']`.

**Input (df)**

```
Id    code  description                start          end          lat    lon
23-A   45   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-03-21      2021-03-28   19.07  72.08
35-B   24   Fault located at Chennai  2021-02-24      2021-02-26   13.02  80.27
37-B   28   Fault located at Chennai  2021-02-24      2021-02-26   13.02  80.07
41-A   45   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-03-21      2021-03-28   
38-B   24   Fault located at Chennai  2021-02-24      2021-02-26   13.02  80.07
27-A   45   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-03-21      2021-03-28   19.07  72.08
78-B   56   Fault located at Chennai  2021-02-24      2021-02-26  
21-C   46   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-04-21      2021-04-28
```

**Expected  Output**

```
 linkedId          code  description                start          end          lat  lon  
   23-A,41A,27-A      45   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-03-21    2021-03-28   19.07  72.08
    35-B,38-B         24   Fault located at Chennai  2021-02-24    2021-02-26   13.02  80.07
    37-B              28   Fault located at Chennai  2021-02-24    2021-02-26   13.02  80.07
    78-B              56   Fault located at Chennai  2021-02-24    2021-02-26  
    21-C              46   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-04-21    2021-04-28
```

How can this be done in pandas

Comment: something with `df.groupby('code').agg({'Id':','.join})`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, Getting an error `sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: Not all `Id` are strings as in your sample data. You can try: `lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))` instead of `','.join`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, works  now. but how do it attached rest dataframe elements to this linked Ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
result = (
    df.assign(Id=df.groupby('code')['Id']
              .transform(','.join))
    .drop_duplicates(subset='code')
    .rename(columns={'Id': 'linkedId'})
)
```

Comment: can you explain what’s not working? @aeapen

Comment: I am missing few  `df[codes]` while  applying your code. But the ones linked are correct. But `df.groupby('code').agg({'Id':lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))})` gives me correct linkage between Id and code

Comment: I'm just dropping the rows based on the 'Id' column after that. You can choose how you wanna filter after getting the correct linkage.

Comment: When I removed  `.drop_duplicates(subset='Id')` linkage is happening correctly . Ideally  I  would keep the first record of each unique `code` after the linkage

Comment: it  should be `drop_duplicates(subset='code'). Rest all good

Answer (score 0):

Use groupby transform, str.cat and drop duplicates

```
df=df.assign(linkedid=df.groupby(['description','start','end'])['Id'].transform(lambda X:X.str.cat(sep=','))).drop_duplicates(subset=['linkedid'])




    Id  code               description        start          end    lat  \
0   23-A    45   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-03-21   2021-03-28  19.07   
1   35-B    24  Fault located at Chennai   2021-02-24   2021-02-26  13.02   
4  38-B     24  Fault located at Chennai  2021-02-24   2021-02-26   13.02   
5  27-A     45   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-03-21   2021-03-28  19.07   
7   21-C    46   Fault located at Mumbai   2021-04-21   2021-04-28          

     lon         linkedid  
0  72.08        23-A,41-A  
1  80.27  35-B,37-B,78-B   
4  80.07            38-B   
5  72.08            27-A   
7                    21-C
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.groupby('code').sum()`

Result:

```
    Id
code    
24  35-B38-B
28  37-B
45  23-A41-A27-A
46  21-C
56  78-B
```